# API BCRA obtener datos actualizados de la cotización del dólar

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Tengo el script en PHP para recuperar los datos de la cotización del dolar oficial del BCRA pero me arroja un JSON desactualizado, no puedo recuperar la cotización del dólar hoy del BCRA tengo resultados del año 2003 al 2018, pero no puedo obtener de inicios de 2019 en adelante. por ejemplo:

```
 {
        "d": "2018-11-22",
        "v": 36.425
    }
```

O es un error del API del BCRA o la documentación es muy pobre y faltan parámetros para hacer la consulta, si alguien puede aportar algo para solucionar esto,

aquí dejo el código:

```
 <?php

    $authorization = "Authorization: BEARER {TOKEN}";

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',$authorization));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/usd_of/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que ya es muy tarde para la respuesta, pero  si le puede servir para alguien más es perfecto.

El problema lo tienes en la `URL`, el BCRA trabaja ahora con el protocolo `HTTPS` y vos estas haciendo la llamada en `HTTP` que es la que se utilizaba anteriormente.

***EJEMPLO:***

Tu estas utilizando esto:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/usd_of/");
```

Prueba con:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.estadisticasbcra.com/usd_of");
```

Intenta quitarle la barra invertida del final si no te dará un error 404.

Yo probé el código así y esta funcionando bien :)

Prueba con eso a ver si te soluciona el problema. Saludos.

Comment: con https y todo por ej a mi me retorna hasta el 28/02 maximo y estamos 20/04... 

voy a probar con esta https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales